# Building intuition in algebraic number theory

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, intuition

How do you build your intution in algebraic number theory ?

Generally my intuition in elementary number theory came from just numerically fiddling with python (and also elementary number theory is pretty easy so you can build intuition without much effort anyway).

But for ANT I don't know any software package to help me fiddle with algebraic number theory -- and on top that ANT is *hard*, so for example how does people even find results like Dirichlet's unit theorem (for an easier example, say $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_{23}]$ is not an UFD)  to be ``intuive" ?

Comment: I don't think anybody would say that unique factorization in $\mathbb Z[\zeta_{23}]$ was intuitive.

Comment: Seems to me the question here is "I'm finding this stuff hard, am I approaching it incorrectly?" to which I would say the answer is no, it's just hard. I do recommend to keep fiddling (by hand) to try to avoid getting lost in all of the theory.

Comment: @RghtHndSd Thanks. Can you give some example of how to fiddle with algebraic number theory "by hand" ?

Comment: Posted also on [mathoverflow.se]: [Building intuition in algebraic number theory](https://mathoverflow.net/q/342669).

Comment: I've been told Sage is pretty good for fiddling around with domains of algebraic integers. There are a few packages for Java, some more worked out than others, I'm sure there's something for Python.